# Number of Duplicate Rows in multiple columns (more than 10) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I have a table in SQL Server and I need to find the number of customers and accounts who have different values across the row.

For example

```
Customer  Account    X   Y   Z
-------------------------------
A             001   X1   Y1  Z1
A             002   X2   Y1  Z1
A             003   X1   Y1  Z1
B             004   X3   Y2  Z2
B             005   X4   Y2  Z2
C             006   X5   Y3  Z3
C             007   X5   Y3  Z3
```

and I want the result to be Number of Customers with different X,Y,Z are 2, Number of accounts affected are 5.

```
Customer  Account   X   Y   Z
-------------------------------
A            001    X1  Y1  Z1
A            002    X2  Y1  Z1
A            003    X1  Y1  Z1
B            004    X3  Y2  Z2
B            005    X4  Y2  Z2
```

Comment: not only C but 002,004,005,006,007 have different X, Y, Z

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I think i understand now after looking at it again. The XYZ values for ONLY the customer column are the same for the C values. The A customer has different XYZ values and so does B. Ignore the account value.

Comment: I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: Based on your explanation, it is not very clear how you go from the first table to the second. Could you please edit your question to include clearer explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First here is some sample data - please do this for any further sql questions you ask:

```
declare @table table (Customer  char(1), Account char(3), X char(2), Y char(2), Z char(2));
insert into @table values 
('A', '001', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1'),
('A', '002', 'X2', 'Y1', 'Z1'),
('A', '003', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1'),
('B', '004', 'X3', 'Y2', 'Z2'),
('B', '005', 'X4', 'Y2', 'Z2'),
('C', '006', 'X5', 'Y3', 'Z3'),
('C', '007', 'X5', 'Y3', 'Z3');
```

Create 2 ctes - one to group together your X,Y,Z columns for each customer, and the next to see how many different groups you have (per customer).

Then select from your original table all the information, and inner join on cte2 to restrict to only customers with duplicate non-matching rows.

```
with cte as (
    select Customer, X, Y, Z from @table
    group by Customer, X, Y, Z
), cte2 as (
    select Customer, COUNT(*) groups
    from cte
    group by Customer
)
select t.Customer, t.Account, t.X, t.Y, t.Z
from @table t
inner join cte2 on t.Customer = cte2.Customer
where cte2.groups >1;
```

Comment: Perfect, this exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @BeanFrog!

Comment: Also if I want to aggregate and count how many customers and accounts have these different values, if I add a count(distinct) to the last select, it gives me an error. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To get your disired result you can use the following query, I'm guessing you don't want to see customers who have the same x,y,z value over all rows of that customer. If so, the follwing query should work.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM <table> AS t INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer
    FROM <table>
    GROUP BY customer, x,y,z
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
    ) AS difacc
    ON difacc.customer = t.customer
```

Result

```
Customer  Account X   Y   Z
A         001     X1  Y1  Z1
A         002     X2  Y1  Z1
A         003     X1  Y1  Z1
B         004     X3  Y2  Z2
B         005     X4  Y2  Z2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this long way

```
SELECT * FROM CUST WHERE CUSTOMER in (SELECT CUSTOMER FROM CUST 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, X, Y, Z
HAVING COUNT(X)=1 AND COUNT(Y)=1 AND COUNT(Z)=1)
```

If any person with good sql knowledge can short it will be good for you.

Comment: I think he means Count(distinct x) etc

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

```
select *
from <table>
where customer in (
    select customer
    from <table>
    group by customer, concat(x,y,z)
    having count(concat(x,y,z)) = 1
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tableau, put Customer on the filter shelf, and on the condition tab for the filter, enter the condition `countd([X]) = 1 and countd([Y]) = 1 and countd([Z]) = 1`

That will only include customers who only have one unique value in each of the columns you mention (X, Y and Z). It causes Tableau to emit SQL that is equivalent to "*group by customer having count(distinct X) = 1 and ...*"

If your columns are allowed to have null values and if that affects what customers you want to include (say if occasionally having a null value for Z should exclude a customer), then you can adjust your condition accordingly, say using the count() function also or ifnull() function.